# AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'positive'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, linear-regression

I've been attempting to fit this data by a Linear Regression, following a tutorial on 365DataScience. Everything was working fine up until this point.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

from sklearn import linear_model

data = pd.read_csv('1.02. Multiple linear regression.csv')

import scipy.stats as stat

class LinearRegression(linear_model.LinearRegression):
    def __init__(self, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True,
                 n_jobs=1):
        self.fit_intercept = fit_intercept
        self.normalize = normalize
        self.copy_X = copy_X
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs

    
    def fit(self, X, y, n_jobs=1):
        self = super(LinearRegression, self).fit(X, y, n_jobs)
        
        sse = np.sum((self.predict(X) - y) ** 2, axis=0) / float(X.shape[0] - X.shape[1])
        se = np.array([np.sqrt(np.diagonal(sse * np.linalg.inv(np.dot(X.T, X))))])

        self.t = self.coef_ / se
        self.p = np.squeeze(2 * (1 - stat.t.cdf(np.abs(self.t), y.shape[0] - X.shape[1])))
        return self

reg_with_pvalues = LinearRegression()
reg_with_pvalues.fit(x,y)
```

After I had all this set up I ran the following command, and it returned the proper output:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 3
      1 # When we create the regression everything is the same
      2 reg_with_pvalues = LinearRegression()
----> 3 reg_with_pvalues.fit(x,y)

Cell In[5], line 31, in LinearRegression.fit(self, X, y, n_jobs)
     30 def fit(self, X, y, n_jobs=1):
---> 31     self = super(LinearRegression, self).fit(X, y, n_jobs)
     33     # Calculate SSE (sum of squared errors)
     34     # and SE (standard error)
     35     sse = np.sum((self.predict(X) - y) ** 2, axis=0) / float(X.shape[0] - X.shape[1])

File c:\Users\Febri\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py:646, in LinearRegression.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    642 self._validate_params()
    644 n_jobs_ = self.n_jobs
--> 646 accept_sparse = False if self.positive else ["csr", "csc", "coo"]
    648 X, y = self._validate_data(
    649     X, y, accept_sparse=accept_sparse, y_numeric=True, multi_output=True
    650 )
    652 sample_weight = _check_sample_weight(
    653     sample_weight, X, dtype=X.dtype, only_non_negative=True
    654 )

AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'positive'
```

Comment: Do you really need to create a Python Class? If you don't need a Class, check these examples: 
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html and 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy.linalg.lstsq